# Delete unknown special character

Tags: python, special-characters

Delete special character

```
 s="____Ç_apple___   _______new A_____"

 print(re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]\s+$', '', s))
```

result = ____Ç_______________apple___   _______new A_____

```
 s="____Ç_apple___   _______new A_____"

 print(re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]', '', s))
```

result= applenewA

final 
result = apple new A

but i cannot get it

i want to delete Ç and _ and maintain space and English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to consolidate multiple spaces into one space, and then remove characters that are not words or spaces, you should do it in two separate regex substitutions:

```
print(re.sub(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z ]+', '', re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', s)))
```

This outputs:

```
apple new A
```

Answer (score 0):

You want 'apple new A' for the result, right?

```
s="____Ç_apple___   _______new A_____"

result = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z|\s]+', '', s)  # apple   new A
result = ' '.join(result.split())  # apple new A
print(result)
```